# Go: Read method in http.Request

Tags: go

I'm reading *Go Web Programming* by Sau Sheong Chang. Here is a sample code for reading data from a request body:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func bodyfunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    len := r.ContentLength
    body := make([]byte, len)
    r.Body.Read(body)
    fmt.Fprintln(w, string(body))
}

func main() {
    server := http.Server{
        Addr: "127.0.0.1:8080",
    }
    http.HandleFunc("/body", bodyfunc)
    server.ListenAndServe()
}
```

By definition, the `Body` field in the `Request` struct is actually an
`io.ReadCloser` interface. My question is: The `Read` method in this interface is just declared but not implemented. Meanwhile the code works well. The implementation of the `Read` method must have been done somewhere. Where is it?

Comment: Moreover, in every interface every method is just declared but not implemented.

Comment: I would start the search with https://golang.org/src/net/http/request.go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation is in https://golang.org/src/net/http/transfer.go#L637.
I used the [delve](https://github.com/derekparker/delve) debugger to find it.